# FTP Waiting For End Of File

Tags: ftp

Most of the vendors that FTP files to us we have the vendor place a file on our FTP server as one extension and after the PUT is complete rename the file to *.FTP.  This signals to our process that the file is completely downloaded and our custom process will pick up the file and automatically process it with defined scripts.

I have this new vendor who state that they are not writing the FTP script and cannot tell their system to rename the file after the PUT takes place.  So my question, is there a way with a .bat file to check to see if end of file exists?

The reason for doing this is that there's a potential that our custom process may pick up the file and process it before it's fully loaded on the ftp server.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until the file's last modified time is at least ten minutes in the past. Alternatively, wait until the file's size hasn't changed for five minutes.

Comment: Good suggestion, however, I think our custom process is biting me in the rear.  About every 10 seconds we have a program called shortstop run and pick up files defined in an .ini file. When a file is found, the extension is changed to .sav.  Then we have another process called upload that takes the .sav file and processes a defined FTP script or batch file.  Here's where I get in trouble. The upload process will change the extension to .bak. So I think I need this happen before the shortstop pgm picks it up. Maybe run a .bat file every day to change the files to .FTP.  Thank you.

Comment: If you can modify 'shortstop' to only pick up files whose last modified date is at least five minutes in the past, I think you'll probably be okay. It's a bit hackish.

Answer (score 1):

might be a bit of a hacky solution, but could you get the size of the file, then check again after a wait period, if it changes don't process. Update initial value?

Comment: Thank you, see response to David.